# Mathematica in my computer vs Wolfram Alpha

Tags: syntax, wolfram-alpha-queries

I observe that if I execute in the url of wolfram alpha the integral of the function (3/x^2)Sin(x)Sin(x/3) with the limits between zero and infinity:

integrate (3/x^2)sin(x)sin(x/3) from 0 to inf

I get a correct PI/2 value, but if I do it on my computer with my Mathematica, it does not return anything, as a result shows me the same integral.

Integrate [(3 / x ^ 2) Sin[x] Sin[x / 3], {x, 0, inf}]

Why? Is it because my computer?

Thank you

Comment: Syntax error: infinity is represented as `Infinity`, not `inf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Infinity` rather than `inf`.

```
Integrate[(3/x^2) Sin[x] Sin[x/3], {x, 0, Infinity}]
 π/2
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I had try with inf and with the symbol; I will try with infinity.